# How to do default styling in swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, styling, xcode8

What's the best way to perform simple default styling?

I'm not interested in styling every single UI element in the interface builder and the UIAppearance proxy seems to be very limited. I am looking for solutions to default styling UI elements with low coupling.

note that i am using swift 3 / xcode 8

Comment: What style do you need which UIAppearance doesn't support?

Comment: I cannot style UITextfield font for example

Comment: what do you mean by styling? please give an example (an image for demonstration would be nice choice)

Comment: Ignore the word styling. I need a default font for UIButton, without having to subclass it. Just like this https://github.com/146BC/StyleKit, I just don't think this library does it the right way

Answer (score 0):

[`UIAppearance`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiappearance) is the default styling mechanism in UIKit. It doesn't seem very limited to me, yet it indeed has some downsides. You should give it a try if you haven't yet.

If you're interested in a non-`UIAppearance`-based approach, it's possible to craft even more powerful custom styling mechanism. For example, I've been able to attach and compose styles in the following manner:

```
final class CaptionLabel: UILabel, CaptionFontStyle, MultilineLabelStyle
```

See [`Style.swift`](https://github.com/werediver/StyleSheet/blob/master/Sources/Style.swift) and [`RootStyle.swift`](https://github.com/werediver/StyleSheet/blob/master/Sources/RootStyle.swift) in the [`StyleSheet`](https://github.com/werediver/StyleSheet) library for implementation details (it's really simple and there is an example project as well).